# htaccess redirect changes encoding of HTML response

Tags: web-server, .htaccess, utf-8

I've set Apache 2.4 server to `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in httpd.conf and my `.htaccess` file redirects all non-www and `http` to `https://www.example.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https//www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

If I look at HTTP response header, only traffic sent to `https://www.example.com` generates a UTF-8 response.
The non-www and http traffic respond with ISO-8859-1 charset.

Anyone know how to ensure all URL-redirect HTTP responses are in UTF-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would seem to be default behaviour, since the Apache redirect response is encoded as ISO-8859-1. However, Apache does allow you to *suppress* the `charset` parameter in the response by setting the `suppress-error-charset` environment variable:

```
# set desired env variable to suppress iso-8859-1 charset
SetEnvIf Host ^ suppress-error-charset
```

However, it cannot be *changed* to a different charset.

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283301/set-charset-in-errordocument-messages
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html#suppress-error-charset

Comment: Thanks @w3dk, the 2nd link states `Sending error pages without a specified character set may allow a cross-site-scripting attack for existing browsers (MSIE) which do not follow the HTTP/1.1 specification and attempt to "guess" the character set from the content. Such browsers can be easily fooled into using the UTF-7 character set, and UTF-7 content from input data (such as the request-URI) will not be escaped by the usual escaping mechanisms designed to prevent cross-site-scripting attacks.` Is my interpretation correct that using `suppress-error-charset` thus opens a security vulnerability?

Comment: It would seem so. However, that doesn't necessarily mean your site is vulnerable. Whether an Apache "redirect" would be vulnerable to I don't know - it's hard to imagine, since the HTML response should never normally be processed by the client. For "custom" error documents you can set the `charset` parameter yourself (to UTF-8).

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to change the charset instead of removing it:

```
Header always edit Content-Type 'iso-8859-1' 'utf-8'
```

This will apply to all request but if you’re not using ISO-8859-1 that’s not really a problem.

Comment: When I tested it worked well, but on another server not at all.